# How to handle multiple promises at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, fs

I am creating a program that...

1. Detects all of the drives on any given system.

2. Scans those drives for files of specific file types. For example,
               it may search all of the drives for any `jpeg`, `png`, and `svg` files.

3. The results are then stored in a JSON file in the following desired format.

```
{
  "C:": {
    "jpeg": [
      ...
      {
        "path": "C:\\Users\\John\\Pictures\\example.jpeg",
        "name": "example",
        "type": "jpeg",
        "size": 86016
      },
      ...
    ],
    "png": [],
    "svg": []
  },
  ...
}
```

The code...

```
async function scan(path, exts) {
  try {
    const stats = await fsp.stat(path)
    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      const
        childPaths = await fsp.readdir(path),
        promises = childPaths.map( 
          childPath => scan(join(path, childPath), exts)
        ),
        results = await Promise.all(promises)


      // Likely needs to change.
      return [].concat(...results)


    } else if (stats.isFile()) {
      const fileExt = extname(path).replace('.', '')
      if (exts.includes(fileExt)){


        // Likely needs to change.
        return {
          "path": path,
          "name": basename(path, fileExt).slice(0, -1),
          "type": fileExt,
          "size": stats.size
        }


      }
    }
    return []
  }
  catch (error) {
    return []
  }
}


const results = await Promise.all(
  config.drives.map(drive => scan(drive, exts))
)

console.log(results) // [ Array(140), Array(0), ... ]

// And I would like to do something like the following...

for (const drive of results) {
  const
    root = parse(path).root,
    fileExt = extname(path).replace('.', '')
  data[root][fileExt] = []
}

await fsp.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(config, null, 2))
```

The global `results` is of course divided into individual arrays that correspond to each drive. But currently it combines all of the objects into one giant array despite their corresponding file types. There is also currently no way for me to know which array belongs to each drive, especially if the drive's array does not contain any items that I can parse to retrieve the root directory.

I can obviously `map` or loop thru the global `results` again, and then sort everything out, as illustrated below, but it would be a lot cleaner to have `scan()` handle everything from the get go.

```
// Initiate scan sequence.
async function initiateScan(exts) {
  let
    [config, data] = await Promise.all([
      readJson('./config.json'),
      readJson('./data.json')
    ]),
    results = await Promise.all(
      // config.drives.map(drive => scan(drive, exts))
      ['K:', 'D:'].map(drive => scan(drive, exts))
    )
  for (const drive of results) {
    let root = false
    for (const [i, file] of drive.entries()) {
      if (!root) root = parse(file.path).root.slice(0,-1)
      if (!data[root][file.type] || !i) data[root][file.type] = []
      data[root][file.type].push(file)
    }
  }
  await fsp.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(config, null, 2))
}
```

Due to my lack of experience with asynchronicity and objects in general, I am not quite sure how to best handle the data in `map( ... )`/`scan`. I am really not even sure how to best structure the output of `scan()` so that the structure of the global `results` is easily manipulable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The results are then stored in a JSON file with the following format ....". Do you mean that the results *should be* stored in that way?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes, thats what i mean. thats how i want to store them

Answer (score 2):

Mutating an outer object as asynchronously-derived results arrive is not particularly clean, however it can be done fairly simply and safely as follows:

```
(async function(exts, results) { // async IIFE wrapper
    async function scan(path) { // lightly modified version of scan() from the question.
        try {
            const stats = await fsp.stat(path);
            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                const childPaths = await fsp.readdir(path);
                const promises = childPaths.map(childPath => scan(join(path, childPath)));
                return Promise.all(promises);
            } else if (stats.isFile()) {
                const fileExt = extname(path).replace('.', '');
                if (results[path] && results[path][fileExt]) {
                    results[path][fileExt].push({
                        'path': path,
                        'name': basename(path, fileExt).slice(0, -1),
                        'type': fileExt,
                        'size': stats.size
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            // swallow error by not rethrowing
        }
    }
    await Promise.all(config.drives.map(path => {
        // Synchronously seed the results object with the required data structure
        results[path] = {};
        for (fileExt of exts) {
            results[path][fileExt] = []; // array will populated with data, or remain empty if no qualifying data is found.
        }
        // Asynchronously populate the results[path] object, and return Promise to the .map() callback
        return scan(path);
    }));
    console.log(results);
    // Here: whatever else you want to do with the results.
})(exts, {}); // pass `exts` and an empty results object to the IIFE function.
```

The results object is synchronously seeded with empty data structures, which are then populated asynchronously.

Everything is wrapped in an async Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE), thus:

- avoiding the global namespace (if not already avoided)
- ensuring availabillty of `await` (if not already available)
- making a safe closure for the `results` object.

Comment: I'd usually downvote an answer that suggests mutating an outer object in a `map` operation like this, but it's an ingenious way to work around the limitations of `Promise.all` in oder to generate the desired results in a single pass. Nice!

Comment: is the IIFE absolutely necessary to the success of the function or can i simply get rid of the IIFE and then call the function directly? ive tried modifying your code slightly to match my whole script by removing the IIFY, giving it a name (`startScan`), calling it directly (`const results = await startScan(exts, {})`), and then changing `config.drives` to `['D:', 'K:']` to save some time, and, although its returning an object with the proper structure, for some reason the nested arrays are empty after the scan ??

Comment: or actually i just realized it wasnt my `console.log(results)` from a separate function that was logging, but rather your `console.log(results)` at the bottom

Comment: Good reason not to get rid of the IIFE. It encapsulates the whole process and helps avoid inadvertent interaction with anything else in the outer scope.

Comment: ok ill try just wrapping it in another function cuz the `scan()` is only ever initiated when a user clicks a button

Comment: Yes, another (async) function would do it. I used an IIFE because the question says "the global `results`".

Comment: still returning empty arrays for some reason. [heres a screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/pTT1VBsj/iife.png)

Comment: Most likely cause is that `extname(path).replace('.', '');` returns a string that doesn't match entries in the `exts` array.

Comment: ill check that when i get a minute. do u think its possible to be completely self-contained in a non-IIFE function ??

Comment: Yes, I included the IIFE chiefly because there was no evidence in the question of a function wrapper. Make sure that your function is `async`, `results` is declared internally, everything asynchronous is awaited, and `results` is returned.

Comment: If it's still not working, take a look at the stack trace in the logged errors to see where the errors arise.

Comment: i will def do that when i get the time to do so. thanks again for taking the time to help out

Answer (score 1):

This still needs some work, and it is iterating through the generated files collection a second time.

```js
// This should get you an object with one property per drive
const results = Object.fromEntries(
  (await Promise.all(
      config.drives.map(async drive => [drive, await scan(drive, exts)])
    )
  )
  .map(
    ([drive, files]) => [
      drive,
      // we reduce each drive's file array to an object with
      // one property per file extension
      files.reduce(
        (acc, file) => {
          acc[file.type].push(file)
          return acc
        },
        Object.fromEntries(exts.map(ext => [ext, []]))
      )
    ]
  )
)
```

nodejs supports [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) from version 12.0.0, so if you can guarantee your application will always be run in that version or a later one, `Object.fromEntries` should be fine here.

Comment: thats def closer to what i want. man its difficult cuz theres multiple layers

Comment: yeah example output of my initial code would be `[ Array(167), Array(0) ... ]` with each array corresponding to a drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [glob npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to get all of the filenames and then just transform that array to your object like this:

```
import {basename, extname} from 'path';
import {stat} from 'fs/promises'; // Or whichever library you use to promisify fs
import * as glob from "glob";

function searchForFiles() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => glob(
        "/**/*.{jpeg,jpg,png,svg}", // The files to search for and where
        { silent: true, strict: false}, // No error when eg. something cannot be accessed 
        (err, files) => err ? reject() : resolve(files)
    ));
}

async function getFileObject() {
    const fileNames = await searchForFiles(); // An array containing all file names (eg. ['D:\\my\path\to\file.jpeg', 'C:\\otherfile.svg'])

    // An array containing all objects describing your file
    const fileObjects = await Promise.all(fileNames.map(async filename => ({ 
        path: filename,
        name: basename(path, fileExt).slice(0, -1),
        type: extname(path).replace('.', ''),
        size: stat(path).size,
        drive: `${filename.split(':\\')[0]}:`
    })));

    // Create your actual object
    return fileObjects.reduce((result, {path, name, type, size, drive}) => {
        if (!result[drive]) { // create eg. { C: {} } if it does not already exist
            result.drive = {};
        }
        if (!result[drive][type]) { // create eg. {C: { jpeg: [] }} if it does not already exist
            result[drive][type] = [];
        }
        // Push the object to the correct array
        result[drive][type].push({path, name, type, size});
        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

Comment: i imagine your answer will work, but it seems extremely inefficient. why loop thru the "same" data/output 3 separate times ?? wouldnt it be better to handle all of the sorting etc in the `scan()` so that the output is already in the desired format to avoid having to loop thru it an additional 2 times ??

Comment: How big do you expect your array to be? The loop itself is such a negliable overhead considering the slowest part, by far, is the access to the underlying file system. Even if your array has a million entries, a loop will be a fraction of a second.

Comment: im not 100% sure but could be more or less tens of thousands of files per drive. ive got 9 drives on my own PC. i know merely looping thru the array isnt gonna take up a lot of time, but if im also parsing every object therein, etc

Comment: In that case, the loops are absolutely nothing to worry about. I just double checked: even if you run these loops in the browser (obviously without file system access) with a million entries, it takes roughly 200ms per loop, including creating the objects.

Comment: Also, you would not be traversing over the same data 3 times. The first 'loop', which the glob library does, is traversing over your entire filesystem. This can easily hit a few billion entries. The second and third loop are only run against a subset of this - all files matching your search criteria. In contrast, the second and third loop do pale a lot.

Comment: worst case scenario i will end up doing something like this, but im still gonna try and get everything done in the one function / recursive crawl. is using `glob` faster than just passing the extensions as an array? can you point me to the documentation for `glob`?

Comment: I included a link to the npm package in my post. Also, glob is a pretty commonly used library (17 million weekly downloads) and it does its maintainer(s) do take care of its performance. I don't think its performance massively varies to using checking the extensions array. 
The actual code for the glob library can be found here: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Comment: good to know. thanks for sharing. ill def have to take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

The function must traverse the file system recursively, looking for files that match your criteria. The recursion can be simplified by the fact that the result doesn't need to retain any hierarchy, so we can just carry a flat array (`files`) as a parameter.

```
let exts = [...]

async function scan(path, files) {
  const stats = await fsp.stat(path)
  if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    childPaths = await fsp.readdir(path)
    let promises = childPaths.map(childPath => {
      return scan(join(path, childPath), files)
    })
    return Promise.all(promises)
  } else if (stats.isFile()) {
    const fileExt = extname(path).replace('.', '')
    if (exts.includes(fileExt)) {
      files.push({
        path: path,
        name: basename(path, fileExt).slice(0, -1),
        type: fileExt,
        size: stats.size
      })
    }
  }
}

let files = []
await scan('/', files)
console.log(files)
```

Comment: the problem is that im detecting and scanning ALL of the drives on a given system with `exec('wmic logicaldisk get name')`. i want to be able to store the results in a json file in the structure outlined at the beginning of my question, and if `scan()` simply returns a flat array of objects that represent each file, then ill have to loop thru the whole array and parse the objects one by one again, which just seems inefficient. does that make sense? maybe my initial question wasnt worded too well

Comment: i was hoping to scan all of the drives, and in this process also sort them, to avoid having to loop thru the "same" data/output multiple times